# Cannot run entr from eshell

Tags: spacemacs, eshell

I'm running Spacemacs and have `eshell` enabled. I want to run the elixir tests every time I change any files in the directory.

This is the command I'm running

```
ls * | entr elixir bob_test.exs
```

This runs perfects through external terminal but when in `eshell` it returns with this output

```
release: 4.1
usage: entr [-cdnprs] utility [argument [/_] ...] < filenames
```

What is the issue? I'm using the `fish` shell.

Comment: `eshell` is a shell separate from the one you're using in your terminal. You might want to try using `shell` or `term` in Emacs to get access to `fish`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Eshell` is an Elisp based shell. Most details of that shell are described in the [Emacs User Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/eshell.html). Also the page [Mastering Eshell](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/complete-guide-mastering-eshell) gives good advice about the Eshell.

Eshell supports globbing and pipes. So your command `ls * | entr elixir bob_test.exs` works with slight modifications.

1. Eshell does not use pipes for process communication by default but pty. It looks like `entr` needs a pipe. You can force a pipe for `entr` by adding `entr` to the list `eshell-needs-pipe`:

```el
(eval-after-load "esh-proc" '(add-to-list 'eshell-needs-pipe "entr"))
```

2. You call the Elisp implementation of `ls` when you use `ls` directly. The Elisp version handles the globber `*` slightly different than `/usr/bin/ls`.
   It prints also subdirectories and their content.

   Prepend a star `*` to your command or give the full path to the command if you want to enforce the external version of the command.

   The following line should work in Eshell:

`*ls * | *entr elixir bob_test.exs`

Note that I also added a star to `entr` to avoid all potential clashes with Elisp internal stuff.

Comment: Still the same issue

Comment: @AswinMohan Please add `"entr"` to the list `eshell-needs-pipe` as I have added it as item 1 to my answer and try again.